# Tensorboard Unavailable: Error executing an HTTP request: libcurl code 6

Tags: tensorboard, google-cloud-sdk

When I try to run tensorboard with a logdir in google cloud storage I get the following error (with various retry attempts):

> Error executing an HTTP request: libcurl code 6 meaning 'Couldn't
>   resolve host name', error details: Couldn't resolve host 'metadata'

I have previously run `gcloud auth` and can be confident that I am authenticated correctly because I can read from the given logdir by running

```
gsutil ls gs://path/to/logdir
```

which works as expected.

Any idea how to proceed so that I can run tensorboard against this logdir?

Answer (score 2):

This was happening because the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable was not set.

Seems that `gsutil` was authenticated ok with the `gcloud auth ...` command but that tensorboard also needed the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env to be set to point to the key file